# How to compare frequencies of categorical variable with 3 possible values

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data, bootstrap, extreme-value

There is one variable which can get one of 3 values and one sample. Lets assume values are A, B, C and frequencies are x, y, and z. How could I find if x > max(y,z), statistically significant? Or, in other words, state that A occurs most often?

Comment: Maybe using a Bayesian approach, that is formulating a posterior distribution, generating multiple samples, and checking your condition.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more context, I would try bootstrapping. In this case this would amount to sampling repeatedly with replacement from your observations, for each resample note if the maximum is for A.

A similar approach, as noted in a comment, would be a Bayesian model.